# parenthesis in Haskell functions

Tags: haskell

I just want to know how do we know which functions need brackets () and which ones do not? For example

```
replicate 100 (product (map (*3) (zipWith max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8])))
```

works fine. But

```
replicate 100 (product (map (*3) (zipWith (max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]))))
```

does not work. It is because I put a set of brackets for zipWith. In this small example, zipWith and max do not have brackets, but replicate, product and map do. In general is there a way to know/figure out which functions need brackets and which ones dont.

Comment: In the former, `zipWith` is applied to 3 arguments; the function `max` and 2 lists.  In the latter, it is applied to only one argument; the result of applying `max` to the 2 lists.

Comment: You can, in this case, eliminate most of the parens with judicious use of function composition: `replicate 100 . product . map (*3) $ zipWith max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]`

Comment: @pat True, but not very helpful for someone figuring out the function of parentheses

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Function application is left associative. So, when you write an expression like:

```
f g h x
```

it means:

```
((f g) h) x
```

And also the type of `zipWith` provides a clue:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

it says that `zipWith` has 3 parameters: a function and two lists.

When you write:

```
zipWith (max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8])
```

The interpreter will understand that

```
max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]
```

will be the first parameter to zipWith, which is type incorrect. Note that `zipWith` expects a function of two arguments as its first argument and, as pointed out by @Cubic, `max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]` will return the maximum
between these two lists according the usual lexicographic order, which will be of type `[a]`, for some type `a` which is instance of `Ord` and `Num`. Said that, the error become evident since you are trying to pass a value of type

```
(Num a, Ord a) => [a]
```

where a value of type

```
(a -> b -> c)
```

is expected.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that while you can't use `max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]` as the first parameter to zipWith, it is a correct expression on its own (giving the lexicographically larger of the two lists).

Comment: @Srinivas: You're welcome. If my answer is ok, please mark it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Rodrigo gave the right answer. I'll just add that it is a misconception to think that some functions need parentheses, while others don't.

This is just like in school math:

```
3 * (4+5)
```

It is simply not the case that `+` expressions need parentheses and `*` expressions don't need them **in general**.

In Haskell, you can always get away without parentheses at all. Whenever you need to enclose an expression in parentheses, the alternative is to introduce a local name and bind it to that expression, then use the name instead of the expression.

In your example:

```
replicate 100 (product (map (*3) (zipWith max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8])))

let list1 = product list2
    list2 = map thrice list3
    thrice x = x*3
    list3 = zipWith max [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8]
in replicate 100 list1
```

In fact, I often write functions top down thus:

```
foo x y z = result
  where
   result = ...
   ...
```

However, as it was said before, expressions that consist of function applications can also often be written without parentheses by making use of `(.)` and `($)` and in such cases, the top down approach from above may be overly verbose and the following would be **much** clearer (because there is no noise through newly introduced names):

```
replicate 100
  . product
  . map (*3)
  $ zipWith max [1..5] [4..8]
```