# Haskel:: Are parenthesis needed to construct an instance of a type?

Tags: haskell

Imagine a Haskell type

```
data Person = P String
```

Is there a difference between instantiating a person with or without parenthesis? I dont really see any:

```
*Main> :t P "Tim"
P "Tim" :: Person
*Main> :t (P "Tim")
(P "Tim") :: Person
*Main> p1 = P "Tim"
*Main> p2 = (P "Tim")
*Main> p1
P "Tim"
*Main> p2
P "Tim"
```

Comment: They're only needed to satisfy order of precedence such as when dealing with function invocations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parenthesis in Haskell functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298348/parenthesis-in-haskell-functions)

Comment: @sshashank124 Not entirely, because that question deals with operator precedence but my question is more directed at the semantic meaning of parenthesis when instantiating a type... at least that's how i see it.

Comment: If you take the answer more loosely, it explains why we need `(P "Tim")` to signify a single argument of type `Person` instead of 2 arguments `p` and `"Tim"` if specified without the `()`

Comment: There is no semantics meaning, only syntactic precedence at work. Compare `foo P "Tim"`, `(foo P) "Tim"`, `foo (P "Tim")`. The first two are identical, and call `foo` with two arguments (one after the other) `P` and `"Tim"`. There, `P "Tim"` is never evaluated, since it is not a subexpression. Instead in the last `foo (P "Tim")`, function `foo` is called with only one argument, and `P "Tim"` is indeed a subexpression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parentheses in Haskell only have a special meaning if they're either

- empty (possibly including whitespace, though this is never done). That's the *unit value* `()`, when occuring at the value level, or its type, the unit type `()` when occuring at the type level.
- containing at least one comma (which doesn't belong to any subexpression inside). Then it is a *tuple*, like in `(1,"bla")` or its type `(Int, String)`. Tuple syntax may also appear in *constraints*; e.g. `(Num a, Ord a)` means basically `Num a ∧ Ord a`, i.e. the type `a` should be an instance of both the `Num` class and the `Ord` class.
- delimiting an *infix operator section* such as `(+2)` (which means `\n -> n+2`) or a prefix-isation like `(+) 3 4` (which means `3+4`).

In all other situations, parentheses merely serve to select the desired precedence, but are otherwise completely optional. In particular, `f(x)`, `(f)x`, `(f x)`, `(f)(x)` and `((((f))(((x)))))` all mean the exact same thing and should just be written simply `f x`. This applies for functions as well as for constructors like your `P`.

Comment: Your last sentence is accurate in isolation, but could mislead novice readers. `f x` is the same as `(f x)`, but `map f x` is not the same as `map (f x)`. That is, they're the same only if `f x` is its own expression, rather than text embedded in a different expression.